# jQuery 'Enter' and 'ESC' simulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to simulate a couple of clicks. A 'Save' and 'Cancel' anchor clicks.

I have this as my enter simulation

```
$('.group').live('keypress', function(e){
    code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(code.toString() == 13){
        $(this).find('a.saveChanges').click();
    }

});
```

and this as my esc simulation

```
$('.group').live('keypress', function(e){
    code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(code.toString() == 0){
        $(this).find('a.discardChanges').click(function(){
            GROUP.find('.group-text')
                .text(GROUP.data('origText'))
                .end().removeData('origText');
            GROUP.find('.groupcount').fadeIn('slow');
            GROUP.find('.group-image').fadeIn('slow');
            GROUP.removeClass('editmode');
        });
    }
});
```

My enter seems to work perfect, but my esc doesn't. I'm running this in Firefox at the moment.

Comment: **Why** are you `.toString()`-ing a number and then using a type-coercing `==` to ...compare it to a number? Also, jQuery normalizes events so that you don't need to check for the `keyCode` property. It will always be there (for keyboard events).

Comment: oh? hmmm would you be able to show me how I could this then? I thought this worked because my Enter simulation works like a charm. Maybe my code is bloated ;-) So make away with my var code and let jQuery handle my IF statement?

Comment: When you are talking about simulation, do you mean detecting thise keypresses? To actually simulate them, you should do something like `var e = jQuery.Event("keyup"); e.which = 13; $('textarea#foo').trigger(e);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `e.which`. jQuery normalizes it for you across browsers.

Then test for `27`.

**EDIT:** It also looks like you need to use `keyup` instead of `keypress` for some reason with the ESC key.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uRE7x/

```
$('.group').live('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which == '27'){
        $(this).find('a.discardChanges').click(function(){
            GROUP.find('.group-text')
                .text(GROUP.data('origText'))
                .end().removeData('origText');
            GROUP.find('.groupcount').fadeIn('slow');
            GROUP.find('.group-image').fadeIn('slow');
            GROUP.removeClass('editmode');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: oh cool, ya i did exactly that when i read your comment but it wasn't working so i thought i was getting what you had said wrong. but yes your right they keyup is what was messing up with me ;-)

Comment: More type coercion?  Try just `e.which === 27` instead.

Comment: ya, i noticed that and fixed it on my side when I compared what I had to what he had proved ;)

Comment: @Ben - Interesting, [the docs state](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) that `event.which` returns a String. Not the case. Anyway, `===` is better, but if the docs were accurate, `e.which === 27` would fail.

Comment: @patrick — I think that's part of the key event confusion.  Some of the key event properties are strings when the key pressed is a printable character (e.g. `"a"` instead of `65`), but jQuery's normalization *should* ensure that `key.which` is always a number.  Even if it weren't, I believe it would be `"\x1b"` (DEC 27), not `"27"`.

Comment: Have I mentioned key events give me a headache?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any html, I just focused on esc functionality.  esc is character 27, probably why your function isn't working.

```
  <html>
    <input></input>
    <script>
    $(document).delegate('input','keypress', function(e){
        code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(code=== 27){
            alert('esc pressed');
        }
    });
    </script>
  </html>
```